# Can't use DateTime in simple c# program

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this really simple code in Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2013:

```
//all stuff I include
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient; //sql DB
using System.Media; //media player
using System.IO; //required for exceptions
using System.Globalization;

//start
namespace Programx
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM yyyy")); // this give error (or any other code that has DateTime)
        }
}
//-----
```

and I get this error in error list:
"Error  1   The name 'dateTime' does not exist in the current context"

I have found 2 possible answear to the problem:

1. lack of: `using System.Globalization;` (but I have it in code)
2. `mscorlib.dll` - included by defualt (I did not change it) but possible cause of the problem

Now I have checked my settings in `MS Studio 2013`
project -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced..." and  I'd not chave mentioned option `"Do not reference mscorlib.dll"` or `"Do not use stdlib"` or anything similar. (but its only a suspect, I have no proof this is the reason)

Could somebody tell me what I need to do in order to use `DateTime`? Thx.

---

EDIT1:

Answear (from my comment):
This is really strange to me, as I said I'm new to c#. Problem is gone, and there was nothing wrong with codes/settings. I changed nothing - just I turned off Visual studio and restarted my pc - that is it, and suprise :), it works.

I hope this helps somebody, becouse I spend couple hours figurying out what the problem is. Thank you very much,to everyone who tried to help me - I will put this as answear if the question will leave [on hold] status.

EDIT2:

I had the same problem next day with another variable (that had nothing to do with DateTime). Again, shutting MS Visual studio fixed the problem. I hope this helps somebody.

Could anybody explain? I suspect that Visual cleans something after rebot.

Comment: Is it dateTime or DateTime? Quite important :-)

Comment: The error message specifies that `dateTime` (lowercase `d`) does not exist.  This is not the same as `DateTime`.  Are you sure you don't have another reference somewhere else?

Comment: And try `System.DateTime.Now`

Comment: Could please somebody tell me why I got -1 :)

Comment: I confirm that in error there is dateTime, but i code I have DateTime

Comment: I'm guessing you got downvoted because you haven't provided a reproducible problem, and the way to fix it should be pretty clear.

Comment: If you double click the error in Visual Studio, what line does it take you to?

Comment: @ BradleyDotNET - it's not :). Maybe I should add that this is my first c# program - I will try the answears in just few minutes. I don't mean to be disrespectfull, but the point of this site is to help.

Comment: @Slapout - it takes me to the line: MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM yyyy"));

Comment: This is really strange to me, as I said I'm new to c#. Problem is gone. I changed nothing, I turned off Visual studio and restarted my pc - nothing more. I hope this helps somebody, becouse I spend couple hours figurying out what is the problem with code. Than you very much,to everyone who tried to help me - I will put this as answear if the question will leave [on hold] status.

Answer (score 2):

If the error says "dateTime" with a lowercase 'd' then the error is referring to something other than the System.DateTime class. This looks like you may have specified `dateTime` with a lowercase 'd' somewhere when you meant to specify `DateTime` with a capitol 'D'. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Search the entire solution for dateTime Press CTRL + F to bring up the search tool. 
It sounds like you have a reference somewhere else.